# ClickOnce publish error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, publish, windows-server-2008-r2

There is my problem :

I've been trying to publish a WPF application using ClickOnce with Visual Studio 2010. The webserver that is targeted is a webServer 2008R2 with II7.5 installed on it.

But my problem is when I try to publish the app on the remote server I get this error :

```
Unable to create the Web site 'http://MyWebSite/DeployApp'. The components for communicating with FrontPage Server Extensions are not installed.
```

I've been looking around, and I found that the FPSE don't work with iis7.0 or 7.5, only a RTR exist, and on the microsoft website, the only thing I found was [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx) which wasn't helpfull at all.

So do you have any idea to fix this problem, or another way to publish on my webserver using clickOnce.

If you need more information, ask them I'll try to give them to you in the best delay.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the FPSE are no longer available (or at least no longer recommended) as of IIS 7.0.

Think about another way to deploy (WebDAV or FTP), I think there is a way to still use the FPSE.

Check this out as well; http://forums.asp.net/p/1545957/3780968.aspx

Comment: Thank you for you prompt answer. I'll look to you link, I prefer the ftp or webdav option rather than FPSE. Will look in that way thank you

Answer (score 1):

FPSE are no longer supported as has been noted. These were required only if you wanted to publish using HTTP.

Now you should use FTP to publish your application instead of HTTP. Set your publishing file location to something like ftp://yourserver.com/yourftpfolder/yourappname (wherever the files are supposed to go via FTP), and then set your installation URL to the http link for the customer (like http://myserver.com/myapp, or however you access that FTP folder).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I did that after the advice of Gerald, and it worked really nicely. ^^